# Unique permissions for site pages + document library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-permission-level

My organization has set up an intranet SharePoint with different departments contributing to the site. As administrator, I'd like to assign unique permissions to site pages and document libraries.

For instance, in the Human Departments section of our intranet, I'd like to assign 2-3 people permissions for only managing the HR portion of our SharePoint page. The HR department consists of about 5 pages and 5 document libraries.

I've tried creating a Group but only see an option to assign permissions based on the whole site? How can I specify permissions to only certain pages without assigning it to the whole site?

Comment: You cannot assign permission to portion of the SharePoint page. But you can assign the permissions on whole page itself.

Answer (score 0):

To set unique permissions on a single page, you can do that from the Site Pages list within Site Contents.  Just click on the page > Advanced > Shared With > Advanced > Stop Inheriting Permissions.  Remove the groups you don't want and add the new one you've created.  Definitely recommend you use groups and not add users direct.

[image]
To do so on a doc library, go to the library > Document Settings > Permissions for this document library > Stop Inheriting Permissions...

Given the information that you've laid out, it might also be worth it to consider just having a separate site per each department.  That's generally how I handle this in my organization and would keep the permissions a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Nate. I was wondering if you could be more specific with the your instructions. After clicking the page, I can't find "Advanced" that leads to Shared With, etc.

Comment: If I click settings on the page I want to apply permissions to, I get Add a page, add an app, site contents, site info, site permissions

Comment: I'd also like to add that I want this page to be viewable by all in the organization. However, I'd only want a few people from HR to be able to make changes to this page. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I added a screen shot showing where to break permissions inheritance on the page.  After you click Shared With you should be able to click advanced and stop inheriting.  As for the read access, you can just apply your catchall group (all users, etc.) to the page with read access.

Answer (score 0):

**For document library**:

You can set unique permissions on list/library in SharePoint by breaking the inheritance. Use below link to set unique permissions on library:

[Customize permissions for SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

**For SharePoint Page**:

You cannot assign separate permission to some portion of the single SharePoint page. But you can assign the permissions on whole page itself.

Page is nothing but a document/item in sharepoint library. So you can give permission to the page in the same way you gives the permissions to any document in library. Use below link to do so:

[Share documents or folders in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-documents-or-folders-in-sharepoint-server-5eec8604-e9d7-4f84-bee5-1c7d8e048d8c).

Comment: have you tried this?